# cant add template to cakephp 2

Tags: css, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to add a template to cakephp 2. The website is called Calm and is found from the link below. My issue is it isnt loading properly.  The instruction were to simple place the files in the correct directory BUT it isnt that simple.  I download the file and in webroot

```
I place index.html in the view.layout and call it test.ctp
I place the style.css in /css
I place all the Js file in /js
```

I change all the image paths to just "images/"

The layout does load BUT none of the images load and I suspect the js doesnt work

http://www.cakephpexpert.com/blog/free-cakephp-templates

Comment: rename index.html to index.ctp, default cakephp image  directory is '/img', if you want use your own, try start path with slash```$this->Html->image('/images/your.jpg')``

Comment: I dont get any output for images . My index.html is called test.ctp and in my controller I set it there.   <?php $this->Html->image('/images/pic1.jpg', array('alt' => 'CakePHP'));
                                                       
                                                       $this->Html->image('/img/pic1.jpg', array('alt' => 'CakePHP'));
                                                       ?>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

rename index.html to index.ctp, default cakephp image directory is '/img', if you want use your own, try start path with slash```$this->Html->image('/images/your.jpg')``